# Drag text from browser into JavaFX GUI

Tags: browser, text, javafx, drag-and-drop, stage

I can't find any question exactly like this: Is there a way in JavaFX to display a GUI (stage) that accepts text that a user drap-and-drops from a browser?

For instance, the user navigates to a certain URL, then copies all of the page's text and drags it into the JavaFX stage displayed. The text can then be used within the Java program. I'd prefer not to use Selenium so that my app doesn't perform any scrape-like activities.

I'm looking for a solution compatible with Windows XP+ and all browsers.

Any feedback regarding starting points, tutorials, posts or limitations is great. Thank you

Comment: JavaFX supports drag and drop from native sources. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by native sources? My JavaFX app will eventually be an executable jar on a user's PC. Does that mean that if they have Chrome, IE, Firefox, etc. installed it is considered a native source, and hence compatible with the jar file? I'll get reading now.

Comment: "Native sources" means from outside of the Java Virtual Machine (i.e. from other applications running on the computer). The native web browser (or any web browser) would be an example.

Comment: @JimJim  Your JavaFX app can receive DnD from any other app, be it the user's browser, Word, Notepad, whatever. Just implement the appropriate drop targets and you're good to go. In fact, the default text area will probably take DnD without you having to do anything, just like it would accept a paste.

Comment: Very clear replies you two, thanks. @pvg, I just tried your suggestion and it doesn't appear to work by default in a text field. It shows a black circle with an 'x' when I drag text into the field. I suppose this means I have to learn DnD, which is a good thing.

Comment: @JimJim bummer, lazy JavaFX implementors. One somewhat related thing to consider is that DnD of large chunks of text is, from a UX standpoint, a very finicky and cumbersome operation, especially between different, potentially overlapping windows. Cut and paste is simpler and if you want to get fancy and your source is a browser, you can write a bookmarklet that sends things to your app over a local HTTP call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Drag text here");
        textField.addEventHandler(
                DragEvent.DRAG_OVER,
                event -> {
                    if (event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                });
        textField.addEventHandler(
                DragEvent.DRAG_DROPPED,
                event -> {
                    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
                    if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.COPY && 
                            dragboard.hasString()) {
                        textField.setText(dragboard.getString());
                        event.setDropCompleted(true);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                });
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(textField);
        stackPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 300, 150));
        stage.setTitle("Drag and Drop");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainApp.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Getting HTML content

```
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setPromptText("Drag text here");
        textArea.addEventHandler(
                DragEvent.DRAG_OVER,
                event -> {
                    if (event.getDragboard().hasHtml()) {
                        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                });
        textArea.addEventHandler(
                DragEvent.DRAG_DROPPED,
                event -> {
                    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
                    if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.COPY && 
                            dragboard.hasHtml()) {
                        textArea.setText(dragboard.getHtml());
                        event.setDropCompleted(true);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                });
```

Comment: This looks promising, thank you Warren. I'll be sure to test it and report back.

Comment: Warren, that works great thank you!! Is it possible to easily adapt this code so that if I drag a website's contents into the field, it provides the HTML instead of text?

Comment: Just like that, thank you! I'm going to study these thoroughly. Appreciated